When I cmake a project in Ubuntu, I got an error following: cmake -E env unknown option '-Xutf8'
I don't know what that means.
I try to cmake the mitsuba3 project from github. When I deleted the '-Xutf8', it rasied error 'permission denied'. When I try to use root to compile it, it also raised 'permission denied'.
So I wonder how to solve it.

"I try to cmake the mitsuba3 project from github." - Are you building that project? How exactly have you tried to build it (what commands you run, with which parameters, etc.)? Your question post lacks many details about the problem. Please, (re-)read [ask] and [edit] the post accordingly.
